# Wordpress get page list order by the sort order

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to list the wordpress pages order by the page order. Default order is by title.

```
 $pages = get_pages('child_of= 22&&title_li=&sort_column=> menu_order');
```

I tried the above one. Bit it doesn't works. Is there any option to do the sorting with the order fields

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got your syntax wrong.  You need `=>` when you're passing an array to `get_pages`; if you're passing a string, you need `=`.  So the either of the following should do what's implied by the code you've pasted:

```
$pages = get_pages('child_of=22&title_li=&sort_column=menu_order');
```

or

```
$pages = get_pages(array(
    'child_of' => 22,
    'title_li' => '',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
));
```